# Query with 2 fields using parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I need to make a query on 2 fields of the same class. I'm using:

```
PFQuery *fewWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FlightsDB"];

[fewWins whereKey:@"Name" containsString:searchText];



PFQuery *lotsOfWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FlightsDB"];

[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"IATA" containsString:searchText];
```

The problem is that I get inconsistent results or no correct result at all.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question.  This is two queries, not one. What kind of results are you getting?  What results are you expecting? You're only showing the part where you construct some queries. How are you running them?

Comment: I found the solution already thanks :) i will give you a point.